# How to compare the generic element of the array list in drools?

Tags: java, drools

I want to validate the element from the list of Type Employee .However the element is generic.The code is as follows.

```
when        

    $dateRollList : ArrayList()

    eval(ArrayList($dateRollList.get(0).getFromDate() > $dateRollList.get(1).getFromDate()))
```

Since the element is generic I am getting the compilation error.Can anyone tell me how can i type cast the list of generic to type Employee in drools.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853310/type-unsafe-object-field-access-in-drools) and its accepted answer.